# What IRC client do there exist for Windows?

Tags: chat, irc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IRC client do you use on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/7547/what-irc-client-do-you-use-on-windows)

I am new to IRC chat. What IRC client do exist for Windows (Vista)?

Comment: This is a dupe of: http://superuser.com/questions/7547/what-irc-client-do-you-use-on-windows

Comment: Here is the original irc wiki question: http://superuser.com/questions/7547/what-irc-client-do-you-use-on-windows

Comment: Yep. Should be closed.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using [Mirc](http://www.mirc.com/) for years and love it.... The way I can easily write scripts and bots to do various tasks is just cool!

Comment: Agreed, but personally I recommend installing the addon-script http://www.nnscript.com/ which makes mIRC a much more pleasant experience.

Comment: +1 thanks, nnscript looks good, when I have a bit more time free, I will give it a good look.

Answer (score 1):

[Trillian](http://www.trillian.im/), it will handle all you IMing needs.  I've paid for a copy because I use it so much, but there's still a free version.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Hydra IRC](http://www.hydrairc.com/) for a long time with no issues.

If you use Firefox a lot you might want to give [ChatZilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/16) a go.

[Here is a comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_IRC_clients) of IRC clients on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

[xChat](http://www.xchat.org/). It's similar in general style to mIRC, but is open source, with third-party [free Windows builds](http://xchatdata.net/Using/UnofficialBuilds) ([eg](http://www.silverex.org/)) available. Also handles Unicode better and doesn't default to blocking all your file transfers, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

mIRC is pretty common. Nice scripting/extension support.

Answer (score 0):

[Trillian](http://www.trillian.im/), it will handle all you IMing needs. I've paid for a copy because I use it so much, but there's still a free version.

Answer (score 0):

I like Digsby for my main IM client, but [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) does an excellent job at allowing you to easly communicate through IRC.

Answer (score 0):

X-Chat for Windows:

- commercial: [X-Chat](http://www.xchat.org/windows/)
- free: [Y-Chat / SilvereX](http://www.silverex.org/)

Comment: sourced : http://serverfault.com/questions/8587/best-irc-client-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

[Chatzilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/16), the Firefox addon is pretty good, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 'best' is relative. There's a few worth checking out though. mirc is the common one, and xchat is the common non shareware one. Both have been mentioned before. Personally i use [kvirc](http://www.kvirc.net/) since at one point, the silverx xchat2 build had a small bug that proved annoying (its fixed now though). I've also used [visualirc](http://www.visualirc.net/) which has an unusual interface, but works well.

I'd also point out the web based [mibbit](http://www.mibbit.com/) client, for completeness' sake - its useful in many situations where a normal client won't work

My suggestion is try a few, keep the one you like